# How can I insert a number to the beginning of a linked list c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a number into a linked list that is sorted in increasing order, I have the parts where I insert in the middle and at the end but I can seem to do it when the value is less than the starting value.

```
void List::InsertInFibonacci()
{
first = new Node(0,NULL);
Node* current = first;
Node* second = new Node (1,NULL);
current->setNext(second);
bool x = true, y = true;
// Algorithm for Fibonacci Sequence
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    current = first;
    while(current&&x==true)
    {
        if(current->getNext()->getNext()==NULL)
        {
            x=false;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->getNext();
        }
    }
    int temp = current->getData() + current->getNext()->getData();
    Node* slider = new Node(temp,NULL);
    current->getNext()->setNext(slider);
    x=true;
}
current=first;
Node* number = new Node(-4,NULL);
// Loop to insert a number inside my sorted list
while(current&&y==true)
{
    // Inserts in the end
    if(current->getData()<number->getData()&&current->getNext()==NULL)
    {
        current->setNext(number);
        y=false;
    }
    //Inserts in the beginning
    if(number->getData()<first->getData())
    {
        number->setNext(current);
        current = number;
        y=false;
    }
    // Inserts in the middle
    else if(current->getData()<number->getData()&&current->getNext()->getData()>number->getData())
    {
        number ->setNext(current->getNext());
        current->setNext(number);
        y=false;
    }
    else
    {
        current = current->getNext();
    }
}
current = first;
// Prints my list
while (current)
{
    cout<<current->getData()<<"   ";
    current = current->getNext();
}
cout<<endl;
```

}

When I try and run it as it is, I will not get -4 at the start and I will only get my previous list. Note that all of my variables have been previously defined this is just the snippet of the part that isn't working.

Comment: Put spaces around your operators. What does this code belong to? Is it part of your main()? The first comment and line of code, taken alone, don't make any sense to me; that's not how a list works. If the list is supposed to be sorted, you should probably just have a single insert function and *it* will insert the number where it should go. Is it a singly linked list, doubly linked, circular, what? I sure someone will post the link, but I recommend looking at the guidelines for asking questions the right way and provide a minimum working example.

Comment: this code is part of a bigger function. You can ignore the first line of code that was just a part of my code from before. the real algorithm is the while loops

Comment: A bigger function **where**? No one can read your mind, you need to provide relevant information. How do you expect to get help when people don't have a full picture of the problem? Because I will say this much right now. Inserting a number into a sorted linked list is trivial. But since no one has any clue how the parts of your code play together, no one can help you with *your* code.

Comment: What's the issue?  Just check if the item should appear before the head item, and write code to handle that case.  Then return.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We want to help you, but there's a lot of unknowns going on in your code. If you don't know how to use a debugger, please learn now. That's not me being mean, that's sound advice.

Comment: I strongly recommend producing a [mcve]. If you do not discover the problem and its solution while making the MRE, edit the question and replace your code with the MRE.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is my full function with the algorithm containing the problem. I guess I did put too little information so this is everything that is affecting my algorithm.

Comment: @RohitSingh Why do you need a loop to handle that one special case of inserting before the head node?  I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: @John [here a list of top secret shortcut codes](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). For example `[ask]` is expanded to [ask]. Very handy, but remember that they are top secret so don't do anything silly like posting a link to them online. They must be kept from the masses at all costs.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks fellow human!

Comment: What is `trialback()`? I can't infer its purpose.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the part that isn't working is the if statement, not the entire while loop. I have the while loop so I can cycle through every item in my list.

Comment: @sweenish sorry for the confusing naming conventions that's just the way my teacher wanted it. I have renamed it for simplicity.

Comment: @RohitSingh -- *I have the parts where I insert in the middle and at the end* -- Do these work correctly?  If so, then it is almost trivial to implement inserting at the front.  `if (new node's number is before head node) { point new node to head node; make head node equal to new node; return; }`.  No loop is required for this step.  If the node isn't going in the front, then you perform the `while` loop(s) you claim are working correctly.

Comment: That new name just sounds like it shouldn't be in the list class at all now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried putting that if statement outside of the while loop and it still does not work x-x.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a pointer to the head of the list and then change where it is pointing when you add a new element

Generally, you can achieve this with something similar.

```
class Node{
   public:
   Node(int val)
   {
       this->val = val;
       this->next = nullptr
   }
   int val;
   Node* next;
}
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
Node element1(5);
Node element2(10);

Node* head = &element1
//add a new node in front

head->next = head;
head = &element2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you node values of your list are sorted.
You need first to set the variable `first` to `number` inside the conditional section `Insert into begininng` so that this variable will point to the node you want to add. You should also remove the line `current = number`.
Moreover, your loop does not work with empty lists. In such case, you have to set the `first` variable to `number` too.
Finally, please note that the variable `second` defined in the beginning of your code will not point to the second node anymore.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, it looks like you've solved your particular problem. But I wrote this code and don't want to just delete it. It does demonstrate how simple an insert function can be for a sorted linked list. Note the lack of an over-arching while loop, and how simplistic the one loop is.

My list is doubly linked, which I prefer since it makes mid-list erasing so much easier. I didn't write an erase function because it doesn't pertain to your question. There's actually a lot I didn't write that really should be included (big exclusions include a copy constructor and assignment operator overload; Rule of 3 is in play).

I wrote a print function as a class member to simplify things, but the reality is you should write an iterator class instead. My personal preference would have been to write a fully fleshed linked list, and then composite it into a sorted linked list.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class Dlist {
public:
    Dlist() = default;
    ~Dlist();
    void insert(int data);
    void print() const;

private:
    struct Node {
        Node(int key)
            : key_m(key)
        {
        }
        int key_m = 0;
        Node* prev_m = nullptr;
        Node* next_m = nullptr;
    };

    Node* head_m = nullptr;
    Node* tail_m = nullptr;
};

Dlist::~Dlist()
{
    while (head_m) {
        Node* tmp = head_m;
        head_m = head_m->next_m;
        delete tmp;
    }
    head_m = nullptr;
    tail_m = nullptr;
}

void Dlist::insert(int data)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node(data);
    if (!head_m) {
        head_m = tmp;
        tail_m = head_m;
        return;
    }

    if (data < head_m->key_m) { // New node goes before head
        tmp->next_m = head_m;
        head_m->prev_m = tmp;
        head_m = tmp;
    } else if (data > tail_m->key_m) { // New node goes after tail
        tail_m->next_m = tmp;
        tmp->prev_m = tail_m;
        tail_m = tmp;
    } else { // New node goes somewhere in the middle
        Node* insertingBefore = head_m->next_m;
        while (tmp->key_m > insertingBefore->key_m && insertingBefore != tail_m) {
            insertingBefore = insertingBefore->next_m;
        }
        tmp->next_m = insertingBefore;
        tmp->prev_m = insertingBefore->prev_m;
        insertingBefore->prev_m->next_m = tmp;
        insertingBefore->prev_m = tmp;
    }
}

void Dlist::print() const
{
    if (!head_m) {
        return;
    }

    Node* i = head_m;
    while (i) {
        std::cout << i->key_m << ' ';
        i = i->next_m;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Dlist list;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int tmp = dist(engine);
        std::cout << "Inserting " << tmp << ".\n";
        list.insert(tmp);
    }

    list.print();
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Your class function sounds like it is generating data to insert into the list. That sounds horrible. A list is a list, and nothing more. That data generation should be in a non-class function, which should then call the `insert()` function of your list. A class should represent one thing well, and a function should do one thing well. These are foundational principles.